# What is the equivalent of this tokenizer code in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stringtokenizer, split

This is a java code for android. I'm trying to convert this to windows c#. I tried using split but I don't know how to go to the next element.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(source, "><");
String marker = st.nextToken();

while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{   
nameLoop:
if(marker.equals("Name:"))
{
     while(st.hasMoreTokens())
     {  
          (marker.equals("strong"))
          {
               marker = st.nextToken();
               while(!(marker.equals("/strong")))
               {
                    Name = marker;
                    marker = st.nextToken();
               }
               break nameLoop;
           }

               marker = st.nextToken();
     }
 }
 else
     marker = st.nextToken();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You get an array from [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) in C#, so you just loop through the elements using a foreach loop

```
string[] tokens = source.Split("><", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string marker in tokens) {
    if (marker == "strong") {
    }
}
```

Or, if you want an index, you can use a for loop

```
string[] tokens = source.Split("><", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; ++i) {
    string marker = tokens[i];
    if (marker == "strong") {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the construct `string marker : tokens`? I have not seen this use before.  Thanks.

Comment: That was not a C# construct, but rather the for loop without index in Java.